# swift 3 core data -output console

Tags: swift3

i made program for fetch data from core data and it doesn't has any problem .i can save data but when i run fetch operation nothing appear in output console .my qusetion is about output console

```
       let req=NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Players")  
        do
        {
         let result=try con.fetch(req)
            for  i in result
            {
                if let name=(i as AnyObject).value(forKey: "player_name") as? String
                {
                print ("name:\(name)")

                }

                 if let age=(i as AnyObject).value(forKey: "player_age") as? String
                 {
                    print(age)
                 }
            }

         }
        catch{
            print("error")
```

Comment: Its not problem with output console. May be its becoming nil in the conversions and its not going into the loop.

Comment: how can i fix it ?

Comment: Can u post some sample data of result?